# For a countable field $K$, can an algebraic closure be constructed by successively constructing splitting fields of the polynomials in $K[x]$?

Tags: field-theory

$K$ countable $\implies K[x]$ countable.

Enumerate the polynomials $f_1, f_2, f_3, \dots$ in $K[x]$.

Let $K_0 = K$.

Iteratively, construct splitting fields $K_i$ of $f_i$ viewed in $K_{i - 1}[x]$.

$K_0 \subseteq K_1 \subseteq K_2 \subseteq \cdots$ is a tower of field extensions.

Take $L = \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} K_{i} $. Then we can readily verify that $L$ is a field, $L:K$ is algebraic, and every irreducible $f \in K[x]$ splits over $L$.  So $L$ is an algebraic closure of $K$.

But is the construction valid?

This construction is part of an exercise in the book on Galois theory by Garling. The exercise asks if the construction is less fallacious than the 'fallacious proof' of the existence of an algebraic closure. Unlike the 'fallacious proof', there is not the problem of comparing extensions $(i, K, M)$, where $i$ is a monomorphism from $K$ into $M$, instead of comparing actual subsets. But apparently there is a problem with the construction.

What part of the construction is fallacious?

Comment: So... why is this tagged under [axiom-of-choice]? Does using AC somehow makes a proof fallacious?

Comment: AC is needed in the corrected proof of the existence of an algebraic closure (which is quite a difficult proof in the book). I tagged AC, just in case it needs to be considered here. But when K is countable, I'm not sure where the construction has a problem.

Comment: With this logic half the questions on the site need to be tagged with the AC tag... :)

Comment: Just a quick edit to the comment I wrote above: AC is used in both the 'fallacious proof' and the corrected proof in the book, and the corrected proof is much more complicated. Also, yes, I should have clarified. The construction in the case when K is countable seems to avoid AC, and I suspected maybe AC was needed because the construction is apparently invalid. But, yes, I was asking a field theory question.

Comment: It is known that choice is needed for both existence and uniqueness of the algebraic closure. But it is not a part of the question here. The AC tag is meant for questions about the axiom. (Let me clarify, I think it's a nice question and I upvoted it.)

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that we don't really have set inclusions. When you construct the splitting field $K_i$ of $f_i$ over $K_{i-1}$, you don't construct a superset $K_i\supseteq K_{i-1}$, but only a field $K_i$ with an injective homomorphism $\iota\colon K_{i-1}\hookrightarrow K_i$. Usually, this doesn't matter, because we can "identify" $K_{i-1}$ with $\iota(K_{i-1})$ (these are isomorphic via $\iota$) and $\iota(K_{i-1})\subseteq K_i$.

By doing this, we can, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, act as if we have set inclusions $K_0\subseteq K_1\subseteq K_2\subseteq...\subseteq K_n$ by identifying the fields with their images under the inclusions iteratively. The catch is that, a priori, we can't quite do this for all $K_i,\,i\in\mathbb{N}$ at once, because it appears we don't yet have a field in which they all embed.

The good news is that we salvage the proof. We can't take the union, but since the sequence of sets together with the injective homomorphisms is close enough to sets with inclusions, we can construct something that isn't a union, but behaves like a union in the ways we want. This thing we are looking for is the corresponding [direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see what AC has to do with being fallacious though; I'll wait to hear what OP has to say and delete this answer in case it's indeed missing the point. As for the construction, the issue is really how we can get from an injection $F\hookrightarrow K$ to an inclusion. The usual identification works by changing $F$ and the direct limit is the natural way of fixing how this fails in the current situation. Your suggestion is to change $K$ instead. I think both of these are worthwhile approaches, but neither is particularly more difficult than the other.

Comment: I see, so then the construction does have the same problem of not comparing actual subsets.

Comment: Based on OP's reply comment on the question it seems my guess was wrong.  I would still want to see more context from the book to be sure what is intended by the question (for instance, if the book has previously proven the existence of splitting fields that are literally supersets, then there is nothing fallacious about the argument).